# Filtering a query using WHERE without creating a new identifier

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is a beginners' question, based on neo4j online training. (Chapter L2: Filtering using Patterns).

The question is about a query for *Actors who worked with Gene Hackman, but not when he was also working with Robin Williams.*

Their solution is:

```
MATCH (gene:Person {name:"Gene Hackman"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie),
      (other)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie), 
      (robin:Person {name:"Robin Williams"}) 
WHERE NOT (robin)-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie)
RETURN DISTINCT other;
```

By trying to figure out why the 3rd line with a new identifier is really needed, I tried the following snippets, which did not work out.

```
MATCH (gene:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
WHERE gene.name="Gene Hackman"
    AND other.name <> "Robin Williams"
RETURN DISTINCT other;
```

And:

```
MATCH (gene:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
WHERE gene.name="Gene Hackman"
    AND NOT "Robin Williams" IN other.name
RETURN DISTINCT other;
```

Obviously I'm missing something. 
I would appreciate any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt:

```
MATCH (gene:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
WHERE gene.name="Gene Hackman"
AND other.name <> "Robin Williams"
RETURN DISTINCT other;
```

This will match all the actors Gene Hackman has worked with who were not Robin Williams, but this does not fulfill the *but not when he was also working* component of your brief. In order to do that you are going to have to bind the `movie` part of the relationship chain. To use `IN` you will also have to use `WITH` as Chrisophe gave an example of:

```
MATCH (gene:Person{name:"Gene Hackman"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
WITH movie, COLLECT(other.name) AS costars
WHERE NOT "Robin Williams" in costars
RETURN movie, costars
```

Unfortunately now you have an aggregated collection of actor names (strings) by movie as your result, rather than the distinct set of actors (nodes). To avoid the string/node issue you can use the `WITH` to carry `other` forward rather than `other.name`. Then instead of `WHERE NOT` you would use a `FILTER` predicate. You still have some work to do to get back to a distinct set of nodes though.

```
MATCH (gene:Person{name:"Gene Hackman"})-[:ACTED_IN]->(movie:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
WITH movie, COLLECT(other) AS costars
WHERE NONE(costar IN costars WHERE costar.name = "Robin Williams")
RETURN movie, costars
```

I suppose the question is, why don't you want to bind the 'robin' node? An index hit and binding the variable is cheap and allows Neo4J work how it wants to work, using the unbound strings will incur a cost of multiple interactions with each node ("Are you Robin Williams?").

Comment: Thanks for the follow up John, your code works and provides the right result! I tried for exercise, and also to see whether I will be able to reuse the same code in order to filter out patterns, rather than a specific identifier.

Answer (score 1):

The second try you gave is almost correct, you misused the IN operator.

IN is used to verify that an element exist in a collection, or here the other.name is a string.

Here is an example of IN :

```
MATCH (n:Person) AS persons
WITH collect(persons.name) as names
WHERE NOT 'Gene Hackman' IN names
RETURN names
```

You can try with this :

```
MATCH (gene:Person)-[:ACTED_IN]->()<-[:ACTED_IN]-(other)
WHERE gene.name="Gene Hackman"
    AND NOT "Robin Williams" = other.name
RETURN DISTINCT other;
```

However, you have now a long pattern, which will be looked in the database. Having multiple accurate segments are more performant. In your use case there will be a global graph lookup which is to be avoided if possible.

Comment: Hi Christophe, thank you for the follow up. The code you provided does not work though (and it's equivalent to the first snippet where I used "AND other.name <> "Robin Williams"). Also, could you explain a bit more why I misused the IN, and if it's almost correct, how can I fix it and make it to work properly? Thanks again.

Comment: You're right it is equivalent to the first snippet. However it is working on my machine. I'll update my answer for the use of IN

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the new code gives and error though.